# User login authentication in selenium?

Tags: java, excel, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a list of `username` and `password` in an excel sheet.

I am trying to find the valid user credentials for a login page.

This is my code :

```
Workbook wBook = null;
try {
    wBook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("C:/Users/jayant.gupta/Desktop/Book1.xls"));
} catch (BiffException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
//get sheet
jxl.Sheet s = wBook.getSheet(0); 

for(int i=0;i<s.getRows();i++)
 {
   for(int j=0;j<s.getColumns();j++)
   {
         Cell cell=s.getCell(j, i);
         System.out.println("     "+cell.getContents());
         System.out.println("i "+i);
         System.out.println("j "+j);
         if(j==0){
             driver.findElement(By.id("textBoxUserName")).sendKeys(cell.getContents());
         }
         if(j==1){
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPswd")).sendKeys(cell.getContents());
            driver.findElement(By.id("explore")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.id("textBoxUserName")).clear();
            driver.findElement(By.id("txtPswd")).clear();

         }       
   }
   System.out.println("\n");
 }
```

I have a total of 6 login credentials in the excel. From it only 1 is valid credential and on position 4 of the excel.

When I reach the 4th position of the excel it takes me to the next page.

But I want to check the next 2 login credentials are valid or not.

How do I do that?

Comment: If you are taken to the next page, logout and then try again, Or foreach row in the sheet, make it a new test that initialises the driver so it's fresh everytime.

Comment: You can use `try/catch` to logout after each try

Answer (score 1):

- Use [parametrized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Parameterized-tests) instead of iterating
- Create new webdriver instance for every test, so you don't need to worry are you logined or not

Comment: If there is logout url (like "http://example.com/logout") can navigate it before or after each test, instead of instance new driver

Comment: @kotoj the more action you do in your tests, the more chances they'll fail for one reason or another. Using clear env for every tests reduces code as well as brings stability.

Comment: Agree. But I think it depends on case. Sometimes the risk is so small, but execution is faster.